# 15.10 Reinstall Failed did Clean Install

Tags: icons, 15.10, reinstall

I backed up /home to external drive and did clean install 15.10 because upgrade from 15.04 got interrupted. Now the system is up and running but most of system icons and folder icons are missing. In addition the applications in /Home folder are not "installed" such as VirtualBox etc. Are there any solutions available or I must reinstall all apps new. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install all the applications again, because you only installed  the basic Ubuntu system. Additional applications you had installed on your previous system are still missing, because `/home` only contains your users' settings, but no system-wide settings or applications.

When you copy back the `/home` folder, the settings for the new installed applications are already set though.

Comment: Thanks so much. All apps are back as before except the folders appear like simple text documents and some system icons. Is there something missing? I am running Unity Desk Top. I also had different desk top environments before but they are all missing. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @AJ-FIN : You can "repair" Unity by reinstalling the desktop environment - open a terminal and execute : sudo apt-get update | sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop | sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity

Comment: Thanks so much. All is working. I have tried to reinstall Skype call recorder without luck. I am getting this message: dependency is not satisfiable "libid3-3.8.3c2a" . Tried sudo apt-get install -- Did not work and same with gdpkg and synaptic. Any ideas what to do? Thanks

Comment: @AJ-FIN : You're welcome - I am glad that you got your main problem solved ... and skype : there are many answers regarding skype and dependencies on this platform - search for them and if the solutions don't work in your case, just ask a new question ... enjoy ubuntu experience !:)